# How to rewrite the images path according to the written rules of the url?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the url of an application with parameters.
I have a link in the main file `main.php`.

```
<a href="index?id=100&title=sub-url-here>Continue</a>
```

In the `index.php` file, there is an image tag with the src pointing to `ìmages/` folder.

```
<img src="images/fileaname.png" />
```

All this works just fine.

The problem occurs after writing the URL.
This is what I have in the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine O

RewriteRule ^index/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

I now have in the `index.php` file:

```
<a href="index/100/sub-url-here/">Continue</a>
```

However, the image path in the `main.php` file is now pointing to

```
<img src="100/sub-url-here/images/fileaname.png" />
```

How can I rewrite the image path according to the written url in the `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Which is your system images directory structure?  just /images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using relative URLs to your images. The *browser* resolves these relative to the current URL in the browser's address bar (unless you have a `<base>` tag that states otherwise). So, when viewing the page URL `/index/100/sub-url-here/` in the browser, the relative URL `images/filename.png` naturally resolves to `index/100/sub-url-here/images/filename.png`, not `/images/filename.png` as you are perhaps expecting.

You need to use root-relative URLs (starting with a slash) that are relative to the document root, or absolute URLs (with scheme+hostname) to your images (and other static resources) - so the image URL is not relative to the page URL being displayed.

For example:

```
 <!-- https://example.com/images/filename.png -->
 <img src="/images/filename.png">
```

See also, the following question on the Webmasters stack that goes into more detail regarding the use of relative URL-paths when URL-rewritting:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: Surely he has to change the behaviour of `main.php` to force it, because I understood that `main.php` was generating that hardcoded image url and he wanted an `.htaccess` solution for it. I doubt it has to do with relative paths when browsing because he pasted the full tag `<img src="100/sub-url-here/images/fileaname.png" />`

Comment: "because he pasted the full tag" - Granted, that is confusing. However, that is also what the browser would resolve the original URL (`<img src="images/fileaname.png" />`) to after URL-rewriting (which they stated was the problem). Are they really dynamically generating their image links based on the requested URL? The `index/` prefix is also omitted.

Comment: yeah, we wait for his response to know it. For that reason I started setting a comment in his question asking for images folder, just in case he planned to create them also in the system or just trick the `.htaccess` to get them from `/images` despite the rare path. Maybe he will share images between pages with that different url paths, that could be dangerous for google images seo if it thinks they are duplicated.

Comment: That is true @MrWhite, the `index/` prefix is also present.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't necessary need to edit the `.htaccess` file. I was just finding a solution to the problem. The `root-relative URLs (starting with a slash)` did not work. But the `absolute URLs (with scheme+hostname)` like this `http://localhost/appname/index/images/fileaname.png` solved the problem.

Comment: I have removed my answer because in the question seems you missed the `index/` part for images (also I am not sure about your current .htaccess because you just added `appname/` to the full path so I guess you have changed also your .htaccess for the index.php line)

Comment: @Kyv If the absolute URL is `http://localhost/appname/index/images/fileaname.png` then the root-relative URL is `/appname/index/images/fileaname.png` (which was not clear from your question, so `<img src="/images/filename.png">` in my answer was a bit of a guess). It would also seem that `index` is a physical directory as well as mapping to an `index.php` file? (It is generally preferable to avoid using path segments that could map to both files and directories as you could potentially end up with a conflict.)

Comment: @masterguru I guess the `.htaccess` file must be located inside the `/appname` directory? (But yes, this is not clear from the question.)

Comment: @MrWhite I think so too... Pity, it is dificult to help someone when things are not clear or changing specs while helping.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Your answers have helped me. I am sorry, if my question was not clear enough. I will try to improve it next time.